# Cant delete windows server 2012 r2 backups

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I created some server backups using the Windows Server Backup tool. I have stopped the back ups and want to delete the files that were created. Even when logged in as an administrator account I cant delete the files that were created. I get the error noting that I do not have sufficient permissions, even though we are using the administrator account. Can anyone give any guidance?

Comment: Delete them from the WSB console or using vssadmin - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2009/06/22/backup-version-and-space-management-in-windows-server-backup/

Comment: Glad to help...